# Block for xPath request

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I need help with an xPath request, in importXML. I am absolutely not a pro in the field.

I had a type request:

`//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/a/@href`

That i had recovered in the field, research on the societe.com page.

The page having changed i tried a lot of thing, the ID would be i think now : `input_search`, but despite that i tried a lot of things, I can't get the right code.

Could you guide me on this problem?

Thank you.

EDIT : Here is the way in which i recuperate the info. CompagnieName is just a example, can be change with any compagnie. I think that the XPath line is not correct, but i cannot find what to change, problem with div or other...

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and show more of the code you are using?

Comment: @JackFleeting : i have edit my post, to explain how my research works, i hope it is quite accurate.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xpath you showed works if you search for a company that actually exists.

[image]

However, if you want the complete result list you may want to try that URL instead:
 https://www.societe.com/cgi-bin/liste?nom=XX
and this XPath:

```
//*[@id="liste"]/a/@href
```

Comment: Thanks @wp78de, actually the code i indicated works again, maybe there was just a one-time problem, to be seen in the next days. Thanks in any case for the information to retrieve a list.

Comment: For the past few weeks I have had a problem with my above request. Indeed there must have been a change, because my code no longer works correctly. Could someone help me, because I can't find the problem. thank you very much

Comment: @Joe Most likely the page source has changed; you may want to ask a fresh question.

Comment: Yes indeed there must have been a change, but I can't find where. Thanks in any case @wp78de, I will make a new post for the problem. Thank you